# python find duplicate in csv and remove oldest ones

Tags: python, linux

i have a csv file with these types of entries, but no headings

```
abcd,123,2017-09-27 17:38:38
cdfg,324,2017-09-27 18:38:38
abcd,123,2017-09-27 19:38:38
cdfg,423,2017-09-27 16:38:38
```

i want to find duplicates on the first column and it should remove old entries based on the third column which is in datetime format?

result should be:

```
abcd,123,2017-09-27 19:38:38
cdfg,423,2017-09-27 16:38:38
```

any ideas?

Comment: Use `pandas`...

Comment: You want it in core python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module which is part of the standard library, you can do this:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict  
# you can use a normal dict if the order of the rows does not matter

with open('file.csv') as f:
  r = csv.reader(f)
  d = OrderedDict()
  for row in r:
    if row[0] not in d or d[row[0]][2] < row[2]:
      d[row[0]] = row
d.values()
# [['cdfg', '324', '2017-09-27 18:38:38'], ['abcd', '123', '2017-09-27 19:38:38']]

with open('file_out.csv', 'w') as f:
  w = csv.writer(f)
  w.writerows(d.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one in awk. HTH while waiting on the Python version.

```
$ awk -F\, '
{
    if(($1 in a==0) || a[$1]<$3) {
        a[$1]=$3
        b[$1]=$0
    }
}
END {
    for(i in b)
        print b[i]
}' file
cdfg,324,2017-09-27 18:38:38
abcd,123,2017-09-27 19:38:38
```